# How can I navigate between words in underscore-separated text?

Tags: netbeans

How can I navigate between words in string values like `'underscore_seperated_words'` in In `NetBeans 8.0.1`?

I can navigate between words using <kbd>Ctrl + LeftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + RightArrow</kbd>, that are like:

- `hyphen-separated` and `'hyphen-separeted-strings'`
- `CamelCaseSeparated`
- `Dot.Separated.Words` and even `'Dot.Separated.String'`
- `underscore_separated_variables` but **not** `'a_string_value_like_this'`

Is it possible to do the same for the `'underscore_separated_values'` as well? (a string having underscores to separate words)

### Notes

In `Options -> Editor -> General` there is an option "Enable Camel Case Navigation" which does this in CamelCaseThingsLikeThis.

In `Options -> Keymap` there are shortcuts for the actions `Insertion Point to Next Word` and `Insertion Point to Previous Word` for <kbd>Ctrl + LeftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + RightArrow</kbd> respectively, so basically I need to tel netbeans that words can also be separated by underscore and everything will work just fine.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197253